# option_for_select in js.erb

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have this in file dvbd.js.erb and it works fine. The expected behavior is that the Dave div will have the set of name and id listed inside of it.

```
<%@dimvers = DimensionVersion.select("name, id").where(:dimension_id => params[:id]).all %>


$("#dave").html("<%= @dimvers.collect { |d| [d.name, d.id]} %>");
```

This is in applications.js, and the .post calls dvbd.js.erb fine:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript") }
});

$.fn.subSelectWithAjax = function() {
  var that = this;

  this.change(function() {
    $.post("/dimensions/dvbd", {id: that.val()}, null, "script");
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#dimver_dimension_id").subSelectWithAjax();
});
```

However, when I change the code in dvbd.js.erb to the following, it does not work. I expect it to change the options for select box #dimension_id. But instead it only changes the select box to have no contents/options if @dimvers happens to return no matching records. Then #dimension_id is no longer responsive.

```
<%@dimvers = DimensionVersion.select("name, id").where(:dimension_id => params[:id]).all %>

$("#dimension_id").html("<%= options_for_select(@dimvers.collect {|d| [d.name, d.id] }).gsub(/n/, '') %>");
```

Here is the code in show.html.erb:

```
<div id = 'hierarchypanel'>
    <%= collection_select(:dimver, :dimension_id, Dimension.all, :id, :title ) %>
    <%= collection_select(:dimension,:id, @dimension_versions,:id, :name)  %>
</div>
```

Comment: just a reminder that it is bad practice to add an active record query on asset files.  these files are compiled once after you deploy so any changes to the database after that will not be picked up by the asset

Comment: That's another problem I'm having. Can't manage to do it in the controller and pass the instance variable. So I'm just doing it here to make sure that this part works. Then to the harder part, which is figuring out why the instance variable won't pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try passing the html to `escape_javascript`

`$("#dimension_id").html("<%= escape_javascript options_for_select(@dimvers.collect { |d| [d.name, d.id] }) %>");`

Answer (score 0):

best way is to have a partial and have the select_tag in the partial, then call that partial from your .js.erb

Ex:

```
#_select_partial.erb
<%= options_for_select(@dimvers.collect {|d| [d.name, d.id] }).gsub(/n/, '') %>

#dvbd.js.erb
$("#dave").html("<%= raw escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'select_partial')) %>")
```

Comment: The other answer worked, but I'm now curious as to why it would be better to have it rendered in the partial..? And thanks for the info.

Comment: glad you found an answer, advantage of having the select_tag in a partial is that you could add more components easily later, like lables etc..